# how to connect to my local server from external network computer or within the same network using c# socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I have set-up a server running on my local host that uses sockets. Also I have created a client application that connects to the server using socket. I have successfully connected to the server  from the same computer but what I am trying to do is that to connect to the server from different computer from within the network. What I did is that I ran the server on the local host and on the client side I provided the local IP address of the computer that runs on the server and I set up the port on 90 so the server listen for connection in this port. The problem is that I can't connect to the server and the application keeps trying to connect and attempts with no result. How can I fix this. Also a point to mention is that I have disabled firewall and antivirus to allow for connection but still I get no result. can someone help.

Code for server :

```
class Program
    {
        private static IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockerts = new List<Socket>();
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting UP Server");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 90));
            _serverSocket.Listen(1);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);

        }
        private static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            _clientSockerts.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connects");
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);

        }
        private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;

            int recived = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[recived];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, recived);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("text recived: " + text);

            string response = string.Empty;

            if (text.ToLower() != "get time")
            {
                response = "Invaild Request";
            }
            else
            {
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallBack), socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
        }

        private static void sendCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
```

Code for client:

```
 class Program
    {
        private static IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.3").AddressList[0];
        private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoopConnect();
            sendLoop();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void sendLoop()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a request: ");
                string req = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
                _clientSocket.Send(buffer);

                byte[] reciveBuf = new byte[1024];
                int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(reciveBuf);
                byte[] data = new byte[rec];
                Array.Copy(reciveBuf,data,rec);
                Console.WriteLine("Recived: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

            }
        }
        private static void LoopConnect()
        {
            int attempts = 0;
            while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {

                    attempts++;
                    _clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.3", 90);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Might need to port forward port 90.

Comment: Yes I did the port forwarding but this is another issue that I ran into that I need to fix. anyway since that I am on the same network same router will I still need port forwarding in this case

Comment: Why port 90?  Port numbers under 1000 are reserved for specific protocols and are often blocked by firewall and virus checkers.

Comment: I have tried with port 1001 but with no luck so far

Comment: do I have to also shutdown the firewall in the client side temporary to try if its from the firewall also do I need to run the application on something else rather than local host